# Can you delete values stored in HttpContext.Current.Application["variable"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you delete values stored in `HttpContext.Current.Application["variable"]`? Or is the only way to do this is by setting it to an empty string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use  `Application.Remove`, `Application.RemoveAll`, and `Application.RemoveAt` methods.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove("variable");
```

Also, setting to `null` is fine since if you try to read `HttpContext.Current.Application["variable"]` and there is no value there, it will return `null` anyway, but of course better to be explicit if what you want is remove.

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove(...)
```